# Adding numbers in an Array with a given condition

Tags: objective-c

I have numbers in an array, odd and even, I have to add the odd ones with one another and the even ones wit one another. I am very confused as to how to go about this because of the parameters and conditions given:

In my Adder.h file I have the following:

```
@interface ConditionalAdder : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithNumbers:(NSArray *)numbers;

- (int)sumWithCondition:(NSString *)condition;

@end
```

In my Main.m file I have the following code:

```
#import "ConditionalAdder.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {

ConditionalAdder *adder1 = [[ConditionalAdder alloc] 
initWithNumbers:@[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5]];
NSLog(@"%i", [adder1 sumWithCondition:@"even"]);
NSLog(@"%i", [adder1 sumWithCondition:@"odd"]);

ConditionalAdder *adder2 = [[ConditionalAdder alloc] 
initWithNumbers:@[@13, @88, @12, @44, @99]];
NSLog(@"%i", [adder2 sumWithCondition:@"even"]);

ConditionalAdder *adder3 = [[ConditionalAdder alloc] 
initWithNumbers:@[]];
NSLog(@"%i", [adder3 sumWithCondition:@"odd"]);
  } 

return 0;
}
```

I know that this method:

```
- (int)sumWithCondition:(NSString *)condition;
```

Should return an integer, but what string am I supposed to pass through the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your `sumWithCondition` function. But you can utilize the `mod` operation which is `%`. `Mod` will return `0` if the first number is wholly divisible by the second number.

This should work (assuming your number array is called `numbers`)

```
NSArray *numbers;

- (int)sumWithCondition:(NSString *)condition {

    int sum = 0;
    int modCondition = 0;

    if ([condition isEqualToString:@"odd"]) {
        modCondition = 1; //Set Mod condition to odd
    }
    else {
        modCondition = 0; //Set Mod condition to even
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [numbers count]; i++){ //Iterate over each value in array
        int thisValue = [[numbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if ((thisValue % 2) == modCondition) { //If value is odd or even depending on condition
            sum += thisValue; //Then add value to sum
        }

    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeshua, sorry never mind, it did! My mistake. Thank you!